# Way to show changes to a particular node to users

Tags: 7

I'm currently looking for a way to show changes that occured on a node and its related nodes.

Currently we are using the diff module and it works great except that it is a bit too advanced on what we show them (ex: html changes).

It there some way or modules to show revisions of a node and it's related nodes in a much simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning) (integrates with Diff) for both Drupal 7, and Drupal 6.

> Revisioning is a module for the configuration of workflows to create, moderate and publish content revisions. You use it in scenario's like this:
>
> - Authors write content that prior to being made publicly visible must be reviewed (and possibly edited) by moderators. Once the moderators have published the content, authors should be prevented from modifying it while “live”, but they should be able to submit new revisions to their moderators.
> - We shouldn't have to grant these roles “god-like” powers (e.g. Drupal 6's "administer nodes" permission) to implement this.